# Django: how to handle TemplateSyntaxError on production

Tags: django, django-templates

I have code like this in one of my model's methods:

```
tpl = Template(u'Some template from db')
value = tpl.render(Context({
    'data': data,
}))
```

This templates are stored in db and can have syntax errors. With DEBUG=True this code can raise and show TemplateSyntaxError, but on production I'm getting simple error 500 and NOTHING is added to error logs or sended via email. Any other errors are handled well.

How can I catch TemplateSyntaxError on production and handle it like any other errors (store in log, send email)?

Comment: If you have your Admin email set in Django settings.py and django can send mail, it *will* send you mails when an exception occurs.

Comment: Email is set, django sends emails on any other errors. But for TemplateSyntaxError it doesn't.

Comment: Are you rendering the template inside a `try...catch` block? Can we see the actual code?